# turkish characters ios

Tags: ios, xcode, utf-8

I am new to iOS programming. I am developing an app which gets some sentences from my web service which I insert into my local database However, some sentences contain turkish characters such as; "ü, ğ, ç, ö". I can insert these characters to in my database fine, but when I output them to a `UILabel` it looks like: "≈ü ƒü √º √∂". I have tried to convert to **NSUTF8StringEncoding** but to no avail.

I have an `NSMutableArray`, named **questions**, which contains some turkish characters. How can I convert this Array to NSUTF8String format?

Sorry for my bad english :) Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahh, I think the problem is not that you need to convert your array - it is how you display the strings.

Check this code which has an array of Turkish footballers:

```
NSMutableArray *questions = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Emre Belözoğlu", @"Gökhan Gönül", @"Mevlüt Erdinç", @"Nuri Şahin", nil];

const char *utf8string = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [questions objectAtIndex:0]] UTF8String];
self.title = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:utf8string];
```

It should now display the title of the page as "Emre Belözoğlu" in correct formatting.

---

The problem could alternatively be with the way the data is parsed from the SQLite to your `NSMutableArray`. Here is how I have achieved it for a Formula 1 app.

In `viewDidLoad` I call `[self loadNamesFromDatabase];` which looks like:

```
- (void)loadNamesFromDatabase
{
    NSString *file = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Formula1" ofType:@"sqlite"];
    sqlite3 *database = NULL;
    if (sqlite3_open([file UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {
        sqlite3_exec(database, "select driver_id, driver_name, driver_nation, driver_team from drivers", MyCallback, drivers, NULL);
    }
    sqlite3_close(database);
}
```

and the `MyCallback` function you see there is as follows:

```
static int MyCallback(void *context, int count, char **values, char **columns)
{
    NSMutableArray *drivers = (NSMutableArray *)context;
    NSString *columnName;
    NSString *columnValue;
    NSMutableDictionary * record = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    for (int i=0; i < count; i++) {
        columnName = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:columns[i]];
        if (values[i]){
            columnValue = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:values[i]];
        }
        else{
            columnValue = @"";
        }
        [record setObject:columnValue forKey:columnName]; 
    }
    [drivers addObject:record];

    return SQLITE_OK;
}
```

where `drivers` is an `NSMutableArray`. The key thing here is `stringWithUTF8String` and you would not need to use the code at the top as all data should be encoded properly and thus will be presented correctly.

Comment: Yes you are right :)i tried your example and it is working but when i select from my database,it is not working and i am taking same problem,i dont know why?

Comment: Hmm, what happens if you `NSLog(@"%@", questions);`? In the example above I get 'Emre Bel\U00f6zo\U011flu'. Could you also post an example of the data before it goes into your `NSMutableArray`. Perhaps it is a problem on the web service side.

Comment: when i select from my database questions:( "Emre Bel\U221a\U2202zo\U0192\U00fclu") on console and on label it seems like; Emre Bel√∂zoƒülu and i dont think about the problem is on the web service side, because i can take the all information and turkish characters and i can insert my databese :)

Comment: Nope my friend wrote the webservice and,it is .net and xml.

Comment: This is a very tricky problem. `\U` indicates unicode character. `00f6` is an 'ö' as seen in 'Bel\U00f6zo\U011flu' (Belözoğlu) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters. But what you have posted is two characters for ö: \U221a and \U2202. How do you save the questions in your database? Also, what database is it (e.g. SQLite)?

Comment: i am taking the a XML string from my webservice and i am parsing these string and i insert to my database, and it is not changing when i insert my database but when i take from the database, this string is changing:)i think, it is really interesting:), and im using SQLite.

Comment: I just looked at an old SQLite database of mine in the Firefox plugin 'SQLite Manager' in which I have the name 'Jérôme d'Ambrosio' (Formula 1 app). They display fine so I assume yours do to. Please see updated answer about getting values from SQLite to an `NSMutableArray`

Answer (score 0):

Can you try another font style. e.g.;

```
myLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Futura" size:10];
```

And what it seems on NSLog lines?

Comment: Sorry i forgot to write that, and it seems on console like that ; \U2248\U00fc \U0192\U00fc \U221a\U00ba \U221a\U2202

Comment: your solution must be "NSUTF8StringEncoding". Use this code in webservice result line. e.g.; resultString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&err];

Answer (score 0):

Here is the alternative answer:

```
NSString *text  = brokenString;
NSData *data    = [text dataUsingEncoding: [NSString defaultCStringEncoding] ];
NSString *convertedToTurkishString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding ];
```

Answer (score 0):

const char *utfString = [strText cStringUsingEncoding:NSMacOSRomanStringEncoding];