# How to convert utf-8 encoded string to Turkish characters in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, encoding, utf-8

I have a webservis in php and I encoded the string in utf-8 like this :

```
$str_output = mb_convert_encoding("MATEMATİK", "UTF-8");
$data_array = array('name' => $str_output);
echo json_encode($data_array);
```

I get this string from webservis in xcode : MATEMAT\u00ddK

I couldn't convert this string to Turkish string.

My json_dictionary is like this

```
2014-01-08 16:17:22.274 test_app[6432:70b] {
name = "MATEMAT\U00ddK";
}
```

I tried this encoding method, but it didn't work for me

```
NSString * name = [json_dictionary objectForKey:@"name"];
NSString * correctString = [NSString stringWithCString:[baslik cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] encoding:NSWindowsCP1254StringEncoding];
```

I got `null`

If I use NSUTF8StringEncoding

```
MATEMATÝK
```

Also I tried NSISOLatin1StringEncoding, NSISOLatin2StringEncoding ...

Thanks...

Comment: check the first answer of this link ,it worked with me:


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14809188/turkish-characters-ios

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iOS is correctly decoding the \u00dd when you use `NSUTF8StringEncoding` (which is what you should be using). That's [LATIN CAPITAL LETTER Y WITH ACUTE](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00dd/index.htm). The letter you want is [LATIN CAPITAL LETTER I WITH DOT ABOVE](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0130/index.htm), which is \u0130.

That suggests the problem is on your php side. If I had to guess, I'd suspect that the `İ` in your source file is not itself in the encoding that php expects. You may need to pass to "from" encoding to `mb_convert_encoding` depending on what encoding your editor is using.

I would strongly recommend that you stay in UTF-8 entirely if possible, and avoid creating a CP1254 (Turkish) string at all. UTF-8 is capable of encoding all the characters you need. In that case, you may be able to avoid the `mb_convert_encoding` entirely.